# How to find out which architecture version from a given .apk was used on a given app installation?

Tags: android, android-ndk, installation

A *single* `.apk` file may contain NDK binaries targeting different architectures (eg. x86, x86-64, etc.). I suppose that, when installing on a given device, the corresponding binary is selected automatically dependening on the device architecture. However, since for instance 64-bit devices are often compatible with 32-bit software, I want to make sure that the corresponding binaries were installed.

EDIT: 
- I mean a local installation for testing purposes.
- I know you can have different `.apk`'s, each for one specific architecture. Assume there is a single one containing all architecture targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Specify the ABI in the installation process:

You can explicitly specify the ABI when installing an app with `adb install` by using the `--abi` option.

For Aarch32:

`adb install --abi armeabi-v7a <YOUR_APK_FILE>.apk`

For Aarch64:

`adb install --abi arm64-v8a <YOUR_APK_FILE>.apk`

Reference: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#test_your_app_on_64-bit_hardware

### Check ABI of running process:

This may be considered as a Hack, but it works for me.

If you already installed the `.apk` and don't want to reinstall it, you can check the names of the `.so` files within the `.apk` file of interest (f.e. using mc). In my case they are located under `/lib/armeabi-v7a` and `/lib/arm64-v8a`. Then you can run your application on the device (in my case Android Nougat on aarch64) and do:

`cat /proc/<PID_OF_YOUR_RUNNING_APP>/maps | grep <NAME_OF_SO_FILE>`

For a .apk installed with `--abi armeabi-v7a` option, the pathname is:

`/data/app/<APP_NAME>/lib/arm/<NAME_OF_SO_FILE>`

with `--abi arm64-v8a` option:

`/data/app/<APP_NAME>/lib/arm64/<NAME_OF_SO_FILE>`

Reference for the proc filesystem: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: Checking the `.so` files for a running process seem to work only on rooted devices (which is not my case), but the solution looks valid, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Run : adb shell
Run: dumpsys package packages | grep

It'll give you the path to external native directory i.e /data/app//lib/YOUR_INSTALLED_LIB_ARCHITECTURE
Else you can use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app this app it'll give the details of libraries packaged in your application as well as architecture of libs installed in your application.